# passing data to tkinter dnd (dragndrop) vs event binding problem

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinterDnD 2.8 - I managed to get it to detect a drop onto a tkinter Entry widget and event.data does give up the dropped text, but I have an array of entry widgets. I used Page gui builder to get the boilerplate code. Page generated code for a LabelFrame that contains the Entry and other widgets and I just looped the code to get a bunch of them.

My question is how to go about passing the widget list index to the tkinterDnD drop handler. I get all kinds of weird errors or just no joy when I try using lambda function tricks and maybe the only answer is to use the good old event binds for this. You'll see what I mean below (second code box) when I show my output.

Also note that a couple code comments have questions about things that didn't work and maybe some implied comments so I'd appreciate comments on those, too.

```
class Toplevel1:
  def __init__(self, top=None):
  
    self.section_Labelframe1s = []
    self.section_Entry1s = []
    #self.sz_text = [] # ugly hack attempt - no joy

    for i in range(0, 8):
      self.section_Labelframe1s.append(None)
      self.section_Labelframe1s[i] = tk.LabelFrame(top)
      # blah set attributes for LabelFrame[i]

      self.section_Entry1s.append(None)
      self.section_Labelframe1s[i] = tk.LabelFrame(top)
      # self.sz_text.append # and what ever i did with it - perhaps setting it to my index i so I could do an
      # add_trace which python3 doesn't seem to recognize
      # blah
      # Entry widgets don't have a command attribute (oh joy, so I gave it a name)
      self.section_Entry1s[i] = tk.Entry(self.section_Labelframe1s[i], name='dnd_demo_entry_' + str(i))
      # naming it didn't help or maybe it caused the prob to which I hinted at at the end
      # which I can't duplicate now, sigh.

      # previous attempts:
      # self.section_Entry1s[i].configure(command=lambda i=i: dnd_demo_support.drop(i))
      # RESULT: no attribute "command" in tk.Entry -- BUGGERS!
      # self.section_Entry1s[i].configure(textvariable = self.sz_text[i]) 
      # IndexError: list index out of range.
      # Index error? What? WHY?

      # more widgets
      # and I get a nice window with 8 of the above and I want to do something when I drag some text into the Entry widget, so:

      self.section_Entry1s[i].drop_target_register(DND_TEXT)
      self.section_Entry1s[i].dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', lambda i=i : dnd_demo_support.drop(i))
```

So at this point, dropping text onto the Entry widget works.  I handle the drop event in the dnd_demo_support.py file that Page generated where I also call a function print_event_info() which does:

```
print('Widget:', event.widget, '(type: %s)' % type(event.widget))
# which prints

Widget: .!labelframe.dnd_demo_entry_0 (type: <class 'tkinter.Entry'>)
```

All that would be good except rather than looking for the "0" at the end of the above, I'd like to just pass the index of the widget and now it gets nearly hair-pulling ugly for me.

The drop handler is like:

```
def drop(event):
  global w, top_level, root # w is key. it's from Page and it comes from the whole w = tk.Toplevel (root) shebang (no. not "#!" lol)

  if event.data:
    print('Dropped data:\n', event.data)
    print('event.widget: ', event.widget)

    if event.widget == w.section_Entry1s[0]: # i'm still forcing a 0 index to the Event widget while degubbing this mess
```

I can't find my other problem, but something I tried caused the script to print a line for every i in the for loop. Dang I wish I could reproduce that. For now, I'd like to find a way to get my i index in my drop(event) callback without having to pluck it from event.widget which as I said previously, gives me:

.!labelframe.dnd_demo_entry_0

and once I unforce the index, I end up with

```
self.section_Entry1s[i].dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', lambda i=i : dnd_demo_support.drop(i))
# in the GUI creation (?? no sleep) __init__ part
# and the drop handler  - something like:
def drop(event, i):
  #blah
```

TypeError: drop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'

ARRGGGHHHHH!!!!  see what i mean 8) I messed with that positional arg thing forfreakin' too long. No fix using lambda self, i : func nor lambda event, i, : func because obviously, event isn't defined in the first statement. Maybe using self.something is the ticket and maybe that's how I got the aforementioned effect that I couldn't reproduce which gave me 8 print outputs. I'll hve to try that after no sleep/work/etc

Thanks again for your time and any help ^3

Comment: Change `lambda i=i: dnd_demo_support.drop(i)` => `lambda event, i=i: dnd_demo_support.drop(event, i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this didn't work the first time I tried it:

Change to:

```
lambda i=i: dnd_demo_support.drop(i) => lambda event, i=i: dnd_demo_support.drop(event, i)
```